# AFNetworking and Swift - Save json response

Tags: json, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I want to make a GET request in swift to get some Json data.
I tried to use AFNetworking and it works, but I don't know how to return the Json I get.

I tried with a `return` but it's made before the GET so I get nothing...

```
func makeGet(place:String) -> String
{
    var str:String = ""
    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    manager.requestSerializer.setValue("608c6c08443c6d933576b90966b727358d0066b4", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")
    manager.GET("http://something.com/api/\(place)",
        parameters: nil,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            str = "JSON:  \(responseObject.description)"
            println(str) //print the good thing
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
            str = "Error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
        })
    return str //return ""
}
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not getting a response from that function, because the GET operation happens asynchronously. That is, the order of execution looks like this:

1. You call `makeGet`
2. `makeGet` creates `manager`, which fires off a GET request
3. `makeGet` finishes executing and returns an empty string
4. *(some time later)* `manager` receives a value back from the server and executes either the `success` or `failure` block.

So the only time you have access to the JSON that comes back from the server is in step 4, and you need to find a way of storing that value so you can parse it or use it or whatever. There are a variety of options here -- one is to define closures that call event handlers on your class instance, like this:

```
class MyClass {

    func jsonLoaded(json: String) {
        println("JSON: \(json)")
    }

    func jsonFailed(error: NSError) {
        println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func makeGet(place:String) {        
        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        manager.requestSerializer.setValue("608c6c08443c6d933576b90966b727358d0066b4", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")
        manager.GET("http://something.com/api/\(place)",
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                self.jsonLoaded(responseObject.description)
            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
                self.jsonFailed(error)
            }
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to return the value after the webservice request is completed you have to pass the data via a delegate or a block(In swift it is called closures)

I see blocks useful here

```
//Above your class file create a handler alias 
typealias SomeHandler = (String! , Bool!) -> Void

func makeGet(place:String , completionHandler: SomeHandler!)
{
    var str:String = ""
    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    manager.requestSerializer.setValue("608c6c08443c6d933576b90966b727358d0066b4", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")
    manager.GET("http://something.com/api/\(place)",
        parameters: nil,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            str = "JSON:  \(responseObject.description)"
            println(str) //print the good thing
            completionHandler(str,false)   //str as response json, false as error value

        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
            str = "Error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
            completionHandler("Error",true)   
        })
    //return str //return ""    You don't want to return anything here
}
```

When you want to call the method get the values like this

```
makeGet(){
   yourJSONString , errorValue in   //Here the value will be passed after you get the response

     if !errorValue { 
         println("The End."
     }
}
```

More about [swift closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Closures.html)

FYI: AFNetworking owner has created a new Networking layer for swift and it is called [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) (AF from AFNetworking is Alamofire :])

Answer (score 3):

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.GET("http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json", parameters: nil, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in
        print(responseObject)
        }, failure: nil)
```

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager is not available in latest AFnetworking library, it has replaced with AFHTTPSessionManager.
This is a simple example of getting response object.