# Getting the count (number of items) in a json response in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, casting, afnetworking

I am on the process of learning swift now. I have used ANetworking (library in Obj C) in my swift code. I have successfully been able to return the parsed JSON. However I would want to find the count of the json items that are returned. Here is what I did so far:

```
//in viewDidAppear function
manager.GET(url,
        parameters: nil,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            self.jsonFunc(responseObject.description)
```

I did the above like this question in stackoverflow: [AFNetworking and Swift - Save json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549627/afnetworking-and-swift-save-json-response)

Now, in the function jsonFunc, I am trying to get the count of the json data as so:

```
func jsonFunc(data: AnyObject) {
    let count: Int? = data.count // I understand that data is AnyObject. How to typecast and get the number of data items here?
    if let ct = count {
        println(ct)
        for index in 0...ct-1 {

          if let parsedData = data[index] as? [String: AnyObject] {               
                    println(parsedData)
           }
        }
     }
 }
```

What is the conversion mistake that I am doing/missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, AFHTTPRequestOperationManager sets responseSerializer to an AFJSONResponseSerializer instance, so responseObject already is your parsed JSON set as Dictionary. Here is the code (refactored to remove some redundancy in casting and typing):

```
  func jsonLoaded(responseObject: AnyObject) {
        if let data = responseObject as? NSDictionary {
           let count = data.count
            print(count)
            for index in 0..<count {
                //data -- urls for the apps that the user has (for the current logged in user)
                if let parsedData = data[index] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    print(parsedData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried adding the above like you said, thanks... It seems like the control doesn't enter the "if let data = responseObject as? NSDictionary" statement.

Comment: Can you print the responseObject and see what's in there? Best is to use debugger.

Comment: yes i did... the responseObject is the json that I wanted. If i try to print it outside the if condition, the json is printed... If I try to print the responseObject inside the 'if' it doesnt print anything...